# In Ruby, each_hash function syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword

Tags: ruby

I try to connect my database with ruby in that example and I want to put output name, surname from members table. However i couldn't show output as `name surname`. It has error. I am new in ruby. How can use `each_hash` in that example? Output:

```
name surname
name1 surname1
```

my code:

```
con = Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ruby')
rs = con.query('select * from members')
rs.each_hash { |name, surname| puts name['name'], puts surname['surname']}
```

error:

> $> ruby membershow.rb
>
> membershow.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
> keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...puts name['name'], puts
> surname['surname']}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `,` to separate lines or end line. It should be `;`. use this:

```
rs.each_hash { |name, surname| puts name['name']; puts surname['surname']}
```

Comment: Or, even better, use string interpolation: `rs.each_hash { |name, surname| puts "#{name['name']} #{surname['surname']}" }`.

Comment: Yes thats good but maybe OP wants to print in new line. Though that can also be achieved in other ways too

Comment: I guess you are using `mysql2` gem because that is the correct one. Here is the documentation for it https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#usage

Comment: Allright. thanks. I got result finally.  `Mysql.new('localhost','root','root','ruby')` is old version?

Comment: I got that error.  `block in <main>': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) from membershow.rb:7:in `each_hash' `  When i didn't use `surname` i got results.

Comment: It's impossible for me to tell since I don't know your database schema and what and how you get the data. you have just shown 3 lines of code.